# Tailwind CSS Nuxt disable purge option throws error in production

Tags: nuxt.js, tailwind-css, postcss, nuxtjs

I'm using `@nuxtjs/tailwindcss` version **3.4.2** and can't seem to disable the purge CSS option. Seems that this issue is floating around a bit and only seems to occur in production.

What am I doing wrong?

**tailwind.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  purge: {
    enabled: false
  },
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {
      opacity: ['disabled'],
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/forms')
  ]
}
```

[image: error]

Answer (score -1):

try this.

```
purge: {
    enabled: process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production',
    content: ['./**/*.vue'],
},
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work as expected. I want to **disable** the `purge` option completely in production because it's removing CSS from external libraries that I've got installed. I've tried setting `enabled` to `false` and continue to experience the error as per the description.